# Add n+1 streams to a RXJS stream with combineLatest

Tags: rxjs

Hope someone can help me with this problem.
I have 2 streams that I need to use the operator combineLatest on. After a while I need to add dynamically streams that also need to use combineLatest on.
Here is what I need to do:

```
stream a ---------a---------------b-------------c------------------------>
stream b ----1--------2-----3-------------------------4------------------>
stream c (not defined at start)      -----z-----------------x------------>
stream d (not defined at start)                         ----------k------>
                                 (combineLatest)
result   ---------(a1)(a2)--(a3)--(b3)----(b3z)-(c3z)-(c4z)-(c4x)-(c4xk)->
```

**UPDATE**

To be more specific I want to turn this [STREAM (link)](https://rxviz.com/v/dJBqXZOq)
[image]

To this result:

```
A----B---B0-C0--D0--D1--E1--E1a--F1a--F2a---G2a---G3a--H3a-H3b--I3b
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add dynamically streams"? Does these streams rely on values from stream a and stream b?

Comment: @ZahiC Please see my updated question with link to an example.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: Sorry :/ that's still doesn't answer my question. Why are stream c and b "not defined at start"? Is it because they depend on other streams (a or b)? Anyway, I think you can define any stream at start, and then I can suggest a really simple solution.

Comment: At start there will only be 1 stream. And as the times goes it will added more and more streams. I do not know how many. It depends on the user behavior. If the number of streams were known, I guess I could use combineLatest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking Oles' answer, simplifying a little and adding test data as given in question update

```
const Subject = Rx.ReplaySubject
const ReplaySubject = Rx.ReplaySubject

const newStream =  new Subject()

// Set up output, no streams yet
const streamOfStreams = newStream
  .scan( (acc, stream) => {
    acc.push(stream);
    return acc; 
  }, [])
  .switchMap(vs => Observable.combineLatest(vs))
  .map(arrayOfValues => arrayOfValues.join(''))    // declutter
  .subscribe(console.log)

// Add a stream
const s1 = new ReplaySubject() 
newStream.next(s1)
// emit on streams
s1.next('A'); s1.next('B')

// Add a stream
const s2 = new ReplaySubject() 
newStream.next(s2)
// emit on streams
s2.next('0'); s1.next('C')
s1.next('D'); s2.next('1'); s1.next('E'); 

// Add a stream
const s3 = new ReplaySubject() 
newStream.next(s3)
// emit on streams
s3.next('a'); 
s1.next('F'); s2.next('2'); s1.next('G'); s2.next('3'); s1.next('H'); 
s3.next('b'); s1.next('I')
```

Working example: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/rGbMGM)

---

## **Update**

Christian has kindly supplied some test streams which are more 'real world' than the sequenced Subjects I've used above. Unfortunately, these highlight a bug in the solution as it stands.

For reference, the new test streams are

```
const streamA = Rx.Observable.timer(0,800).map(x => String.fromCharCode(x+ 65));
const streamB = Rx.Observable.timer(0,1300).map(x => x);
const streamC = Rx.Observable.timer(1100, 2000).map(x => String.fromCharCode(x+ 97));

setTimeout(() => newStream.next(streamA), 500);
setTimeout(() => newStream.next(streamB), 2000);
setTimeout(() => newStream.next(streamC), 3000);
```

**Problem #1**

The first problem stems from the core line in `streamOfStreams`,

```
  .switchMap(vs => Observable.combineLatest(vs))
```

This essentially says, every time a new array of streams appears, map it to a `combineLatest()` of the new array and switch to the new observable. However, the test observables are cold, which means each re-subscription gets the full stream.

Ref: [Introduction to Rx - Hot and Cold observables](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html)

> Some observable sequences can appear to be hot when they are in fact
>   cold. A couple of examples that surprise many is Observable.Interval
>   and Observable.Timer

So we get
- expected `A--B--B0...`
- actual `A--B--A0--B0...`

The obvious solution is to turn the cold observables hot,

```
const asHot = (stream) => {
  const hot = stream.multicast(() => new Rx.Subject())
  hot.connect()
  return hot
}
```

but this omits B0 from the sequence, `A--B--C0...`, so we want hot + 1 previous which can be had with a buffer size one

```
const asBuffered = (stream) => {
  const bufferOne = new ReplaySubject(1)
  stream.subscribe(value => bufferOne.next(value))
  return bufferOne
}
```

**Problem #2**

The second problem comes from the fact that streamC delays it's first emit by 1100ms (good test Christian!).

This results is
- expected `A--B--B0--C0--D0--D1--E1--E1a...`
- actual `A--B--B0--C0--D0--E1a...`

which means we need to delay adding a stream until it's first emit

```
const addStreamOnFirstEmit = (stream) => {
  const buffered = asBuffered(stream)
  buffered.first().subscribe( _ => {
    newStream.next(buffered)
  })
}
```

Working example: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/xXeavp)

### ***Notes on the CodePen***

I've left in the various **streamAdder** functions for experimentation, and there are also `_debug` versions that emit the streams and the addStream events to show the sequence.

Also limited the source streams so that the console doesn't scroll too much.

### ***Note on the expected output***

The new solution diverges from the expected output given in the question after 'G3a'

- expected `A----B---B0-C0--D0--D1--E1--F1---F2---F2a---G2a---G3a--H3a--H3b--I3b`
- actual `A----B---B0-C0--D0--D1--E1--E1a--F1a--F2a---G2a---G3a--G3b--H3b--I3b`

which is due to the simultaneous emission of of 'H' and 'b'. Problem #3?

### ***One more test***

In order to see if the solution failed if streamC delayed first emission until after **two** emits of streamA & streamB, I changed the delay to 1800ms

```
const streamC = Rx.Observable.timer(1800, 2000).map(x => String.fromCharCode(x+ 97));
```

I believe the output for this test is correct.

Comment: Thanks for creating a Codepen with the given input :)  I see that you are using replySubject for the new streams. I'm using Firebase and it is returning a Observable. Is it possible to achieve the same result with Observable?

Comment: Yes, most of the Subjects are just there to simulate the correct emit sequence, except for newStream - you will have to keep that and feed each new stream to streamOfStreams, so s1, s2, etc should work with any observable.

Comment: Christian, I approved the changes you suggested, but not sure if they went through.

Comment: The CodePen seems to work with ReplaySubject instead of Subject. The reason I used Replay's in the first answer was to switch subscriptions, in the second answer they didn't seem necessary - as I mention s1-s3 are Subjects just to simulate the test sequence, but any Observable source should work. BTW, usually ReplaySubject has a bufferSize param, not sure what you get if it's omitted.

Comment: Also, would like to try the CodePen code on rxviz, do you still have the code for the streams when you created the diagram?

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was so after 3 of your links came up 404 - who could be that unlucky :).

Comment: If I use something else than replaySubject I do not get the result I want..

Comment: Ok, so ReplaySubject is buffering. I tried the scan on rxviz with the observable sources you gave me, but the output is wrong - it does not combineLatest, instead I get [A, B, A0, B0... Is this related to use of ReplaySubject? I will tackle this tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks a million! I'll be waiting for your reply! I will also try tomorrow. I'll post my answer if I can find a solution. But I am quite new to rxjs..

Comment: Thank you so much! The biggest problem that hot vs cold observables!

Comment: Cheers Christian, it was your clue about ReplaySubject that gave the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The idea it that [everything is a stream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c17sD.jpg). Even stream of streams :)

```js
const onNew$ = new Rx.Subject();

const a$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).mapTo('a');
const b$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).mapTo('b');

const comb$ = Rx.Observable
  .merge(
    onNew$,
    Rx.Observable.from([a$, b$]),
  )
  .scan((acc, v) => {
      acc.push(v);
      return acc;
    }, [])
  .switchMap(vs => Rx.Observable.combineLatest(vs))

comb$.take(4).subscribe(v => console.log(v));

setTimeout(
  () => onNew$.next(Rx.Observable.interval(1000).mapTo('c')),
  2000,
);
setTimeout(
  () => onNew$.next(Rx.Observable.interval(1000).mapTo('d')),
  4000,
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes I need a stream of streams:) Thanks. But I cannot get the result I am looking for in your example. I created an startstream here: https://rxviz.com/v/lJ0kQbO6   And I want to return the following stream:  A----B---B0-C0--D0--D1--E1--E1a--F1a--F2a---G2a---G3a--H3a-H3b--I3b

Comment: Seems like you forgot to add `.scan` and `.combineLatest`. And now your link is broken

Answer (score 0):

Can be done if you can unsubscribe and re-subscribe for each new stream

```
// Start with two streams
const s1 = new ReplaySubject(1) 
const s2 = new ReplaySubject(1) 
let out = Observable.combineLatest(s1, s2)
let subscription = out.subscribe(console.log)
s2.next('1'); s1.next('a'); s2.next('2'); s2.next('3'); s1.next('b')

// Add a new stream
subscription.unsubscribe()
const s3 = new ReplaySubject(1) 
out = Observable.combineLatest(s1, s2, s3)
subscription = out.subscribe(console.log)
s3.next('z'); s1.next('c'); s2.next('4'); s3.next('x')

// Add a new stream
subscription.unsubscribe()
const s4 = new ReplaySubject(1) 
out = Observable.combineLatest(s1, s2, s3, s4)
subscription = out.subscribe(console.log)
s4.next('k')
```

Working example: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/bomKWx)

Comment: Thanks I tried, but I get a small delay/lack which I do not want to have in my application.

Comment: Yes, I see. I think Oles is on the right track, just his sample needs a tidy up.